# map reduce error on smoke test

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have configured the hadoop on my machine using hartonworks msi on windows . When i run the `run-somketest.cmd` im getting the following error

```
java.net.ConnectException: Call to DEV144/192.168.137.1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at $Proxy2.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at $Proxy2.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createNamenode(DFSClie
```

Actually what went wrong and how to over come it

Thanks all

Comment: I think `connection refused` is a pretty clear error message. Does your namenode have enough handlers to handle the requests?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut im newbie to this and also im getting error in Hbase service also .. http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/hbase-master-hbase-regionsserver-services-wont-start/ refer this im getting the same problem also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to check the core-site.xml file to check **fs.defaultFS** property.**This is used to specify the default file system and defaults to your local file system that's why it needs be set to a HDFS address. This is important for client configuration as well so your local configuration file should include this element.**

In your case based on the error I can see "DEV144/192.168.137.1:8020".

**fs.defaultFS** - the default path prefix used by the Hadoop FS client when none is given

Optionally, you may now configure the default path for Hadoop clients to use the new HA-enabled logical URI. If you used "mycluster" as the nameservice ID earlier, this will be the value of the authority portion of all of your HDFS paths. This may be configured like so, in your core-site.xml file:

```
<property><name>fs.defaultFS</name><value>hdfs://mycluster</value></property>
```

Check this link [details of this property](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm_chap3.html)

Comment: Are you sure this is going to work? Have you tried this before?

Comment: you mean to say DEV144/192.168.137.1:8020 is the value of the property `fs.defaultFS` when none is set?

Comment: No no actually DEV144/192.168.137.1:8020 was configured wrongly that is why it was not working @SSaikia_JtheRocker